# Get value of field from link

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have link with onclick function and I need to insert in this event onclick the value of field for send to function I put my little code

```
<br />
<input type="text" name="val_number" id="vals" value=""/>
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="add_values("$('#vals').val()");">Add Values</a>
```

As you can see, I need to get the text insert in `val_number` for send when onclick - `add_values` - event it's activate, but doesn't get finally value of field, I don't know however what I write bad.

Comment: `onclick="add_values($('#vals').val());"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had some extra quotes in there you don't need:

```
<a href="#" onclick="add_values($('#vals').val());">Add Values</a>
```